# Does this conditional independence hold?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, binomial-distribution

I have a random variable $X$, where $0<X<1$; and a random variable $Y$. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent.

If I let $Z \sim binomial(p=X)$. $Z=X$ with $p=X$ and $Z=1-X$ with $p=1-X$. Is it true that $Z \mathrel{\perp\mspace{-10mu}\perp} Y|X$?

Comment: $\perp$, in this context, refers to independence, correct?

Comment: Yes, Clarinetist.  My thinking is conditional on $X$, $X$ is like a constant, so $X \mathrel{\perp\mspace{-10mu}\perp} Y|X$. Since $Z$ is a function of $X$, so we have $Z \mathrel{\perp\mspace{-10mu}\perp} Y|X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim doesn't hold. Let $X$ be uniform $(0,1)$, and given $X$ let $Z$ be binomial$(1,X)$, i.e. $Z$ is a single toss of a coin with success probability $X$. You can calculate that for any interval $(a,b)$ inside $(0,1)$,
$$
\textstyle P(Z=1\mid X\in(a,b)) = \frac12(a+b).
$$
Now define $Y$ so that $(X,Y)$ has a 'triangle' shape: $Y=h(X)$, where
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $0<x<\frac12$} \\
1-x, & \text{if $\frac12\le x<1$}
\end{cases}\;.
$$
Then $Y$ and $X$ are uncorrelated, but
$$\textstyle P(Z=1\mid X<\frac12)=\frac14$$
while
$$\textstyle P(Z=1\mid Y>\frac14,X<\frac12)=P(Z=1\mid X\in(\frac14,\frac12))=\frac38$$

Comment: Hi Grand_chat. It is one elegant example. X is a range in your example. What if X=x?

Comment: @Vincent Do you mean if $X$ is a constant? Then $X$ is independent of any $Y$, so you can choose any $Y$ such that $P(Z=1\mid Y\in A) \neq P(Z=1)$ as a counterexample. For example let $(X,Y,Z)$ be discrete with mass $1/4$ on $(1/2,1,1)$, mass $1/4$ on $(1/2,0,1)$ and mass $1/2$ on $(1/2,0,0)$. Then $P(Z=1\mid Y=1,X=1/2)=1/4\neq 1/2=P(Z=1\mid X=1/2)$.